# Remove and Add modules in wazuh

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, wazuh

I have been using Wazuh for a few months now. I am trying to remove the two following modules from the interface and add my own module and direct it to another page. Thank you in advance!

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zZEr.png)

I tried to look into the modules from the interface itself to disable it but some of it cannot be disabled by default. I hope to get some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for using Wazuh!

To remove unwanted modules from Wazuh GUI, you need to go to **Wazuh > Settings > Modules menu**:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHrkE.png)

There are some modules that can not be hidden through configuration. So, if you want to hide them, then you will have to modify the code of the Wazuh plugin.

There are two options to achieve this:

**1. Modify the source code of the plugin, build an installable package and install it in your Wazuh dashboard or Kibana**

Develop new features: https://github.com/wazuh/wazuh-kibana-app/wiki/Develop-new-features

Build an installable package: https://github.com/wazuh/wazuh-kibana-app/wiki/Build-Wazuh-app-package

Depending on the version of the Wazuh plugin you want to generate with the changes, you should select the related branch or tag to apply your changes.

**2. Modify the code of the installed plugin**

This approach is only recommended for small changes. The unsupported customization documentation uses this approach (https://github.com/wazuh/wazuh-kibana-app/wiki/Customization#unsupported-customization).

If you want to add modules to the Wazuh plugin, then you will have to explore the source code of the Wazuh plugin to see where and what are changes you need to do.

As you can imagine, modifying the source code of the Wazuh plugin requires some knowledge, and could be hard to know what changes you have to do.

If your goal is to create custom visualizations in a dashboard, I would recommend you use the Dashboard plugin to create a custom dashboard with your custom visualizations outside of the Wazuh plugin. For further information, please refer to the following documentation:
[Wazuh - Custom dashboard](https://documentation.wazuh.com/4.2/user-manual/kibana-app/reference/custom-dashboard.html)

I hope this information would be useful for you.

Best regards,

Nicolás.